# $\exists x \in N, \forall y \in N, x \ge y$

Tags: inequality

$\exists x \in N, \forall y \in N, x \ge  y$

Why is this a false statement?

Intuitively, it seems that if you let x always equal y, then the statement always holds true.

Comment: It says there is a number which is $\ge$ **all** numbers. False, since given any number $x$ you can always name a bigger one. You don't get to choose $y$ first.

Comment: Suppose there is such a x. Take y= x+1

Comment: Thank you both! I was thinking about it in the wrong way.

Comment: You are welcome. Quantifiers are read from left to right.

Comment: So, this statement is true when the quantifiers are reversed?

Comment: Yes, it is true if the quantifiers are reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the statement: $\color{blue}{ \exists x \in N, \forall y \in N, x\geq y}$

This statements reads: There exists a natural number ($x$), that for all natural numbers ($y$), $x$ is greater than or equal to $y$.

Which can be paraphrased as: There is one natural number which is greater than or equal to *all* of the natural numbers.

Or simply: There is a largest natural number.

Which is clearly false.

---

Contrast that to the statement: $\color{blue}{ \forall y \in N, \exists x \in N, x\geq y}$

Which reads: For all natural numbers there exists a natural number which is larger than or equal to it.

This statement is true.

Hence demonstrating that the order of the quantifiers makes has a significant impact as to the *meaning* of the statement.  They are not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

The statement says that there is $x\in\Bbb N$, that when **fixed**, no matter what $y\in\Bbb N$ we pick, $x\geq y$.

If that was true, what happens when $y=x+1$?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition say that $\mathbb N$ is bounded. May be $$\exists x\in\mathbb N:\forall y\in\mathbb N, y\leq x$$
will make more sense (even if it's **exactly** the same thing, I'm usually ease with $\leq$ than $\geq$)

Then if $$\exists x\in\mathbb N: \forall y\in\mathbb N, y\leq x$$
you have to understand that there exists an element $x\in\mathbb N$ such that all natural numbers are in $[0,x]$ which is impossible because $\mathbb N$ is unbounded. Do you understand ?